# Good books for non-Jews who are interested in understanding Judaism, especially branches of Orthodox judaism

Tags: gentiles, orthodox, books-generally, product-recommendation

I have found that the first thing to do when you want to learn something about a subject, is to start with the idea that you know absolutely nothing.  I understand, for example, that Judaism has either branches, or sects, or various subgroups.  I'm interested in understanding Orthodoxy, which I understand isn't even one branch, but a bunch of branches.

(Update: if "branch" is an incorrect word, please understand that I mean only, groups which could be held distinct in some way, from the rest of Orthodox Judaism.)

What is a good book that helps with understanding Orthodox Judaism, as it exists today and is practiced, it's history and ideas and most of all, the underlying principles or forms, or ideas, which make it itself. A good book for me would answer these questions:

- What do the authorities within Orthodox judaism say about Orthodox Judaism. How do they define it?
- What is the daily life of those comitted to the practices of Orthodoxy look like, including the practice of "Shabbat/"Shabbos"
- Introducing the the study of Torah, Tanakh, and Talmud, as it is understood by Orthodox authorities.

I realize that all of the above are worthy of their own books. But imagine, you simply want somewhere to start. is there a good book on what Orthodox judaism is, that addresses at least a little bit of those subject areas, that would be readable by someone with zero knowledge of Hebrew?

The most important thing I want to know is that the view in the book is presented by those who themselves hold the views they are describing. That is, I am not looking for an external, or academic view. I am looking for an internal view, but perhaps written so that those who are not part of the religion, or practicing it themselves, might be able to understand it.

Comment: You should know that the Jewish tradition does not distinguish among branches of Judaism. There are tribes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribal_allotments_of_Israel, but they have little significance nowadays. There are so-called Ashkenazic and Sepharadic Jews (and some others), but that's just a name given to Jews who have lived in various areas and developed their own culture and practices; there's no real difference between an Ashkenazi and a Sepharadi like there is between, though I hate to make the comparison, a Catholic and a Protestant. [continued]

Comment: [continued] "Conservative", "Orthodox", "Reform", etc. — these are, from the perspective of (lowercase-'o') orthodox Judaism, meaningless designations: all Jews are just plain Jews, though some may follow more of the dictates of the Torah and others less (or, unlikely, none). (There are categories called, in Hebrew, "mumar", "min", etc., but those don't correspond to "Reform" etc. by any means.) Within so-called Orthodoxy, the groups called "Chasid", "Mitnaged", etc. — these, too, are meaningless really, and many people have switched from being called one to being called another. [continued]

Comment: [continued] While I know my comment doesn't help to answer your question (and that's why I included it as a comment rather than as an answer), I just wanted to respond to your "Judaism has branches. I'm interested in understanding Orthodoxy, which I understand isn't even one branch, but a bunch of branches".

Comment: Warren P, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for this important question! I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: Maybe my terminology is wrong.   For example, I have an Orthodox email-penpal who lives in Jerusalem, and is a member of a sect, or group, within Orthodox Judaism.  Perhaps sect, or subgroup is a better word, than branch?

Comment: "Sect" or "subgroup" or "branch" is fine. I'm just saying that these divisions are ultimately meaningless. A "chasid" or "mitnaged" or "haredi" or "Modern Orthodox" person or "dati-leumi" person is, when it boils down to it, just a practicing Jew. And many, many a person has switched from one of those descriptions to another with no identity crisis, with no papers filed, sometimes without changing his circle of friends.

Comment: @Warren Take a look at this Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_religious_movements#Modern_divisions_or_denominations In particular, I like its description of Orthodox: "Orthodox Jews generally see themselves as practicing normative Judaism, rather than belonging to a particular movement. Within Orthodox Judaism there is a spectrum of communities and practices, including Modern Orthodox Judaism, Haredi Judaism, and a variety of movements that have their origins in Hasidic Judaism." (continued)

Comment: (continued) The reason you see "Orthodox" as having a bunch of branches is that unlike the defined Reform, Conservative, etc. movements, "Orthodox" really just means "all those who stick with the tradition that was there before people started creating new 'movements'," so that includes all different kinds of communities, some of whom have never heard of the term "Orthodox," with no single, central authority.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Chasidim wasn't considered a new movement when it started?  It's just so different than what came before.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman, it was, and that's why it was so strongly opposed.

Comment: [That's](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6988/good-books-for-non-jews-who-are-interested-in-understanding-judaism-especially#comment44780_6988) what I thought.  @IsaacMoses - In light of that, how can you say that Orthodox Judaism doesn't have branches?  Or that it's people just going on tradition.  Seems wrong and simplistic to me.

Comment: Very similar (maybe a duplicate): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30022

Comment: See also the books mentioned here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10739/resources-for-learning-about-the-foundations-of-judaism

Answer (score 11):

1. *Horeb*, by [Rabbi Samson Raphael Hirsch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samson_Raphael_Hirsch), is definitely directed to a Jewish audience, but is, I suspect, largely comprehensible by others.
2. [Herman Wouk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herman_Wouk)'s [*This Is My God*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Is_My_God%3a_The_Jewish_Way_of_Life) is directed mostly to an irreligious Jewish audience, but was interesting to me (a religious Jew) also and is certainly comprehensible by non-Jews.

Comment: +1 for Horeb (http://www.amazon.com/Horeb-Philosophy-Jewish-Laws-Observances/dp/0900689404). It summarizes something resembling the gamut of Jewish observances, observance by observance, giving all the "whats" "hows" and "whys" from R' Hirsch's point of view, which has had an important influence on contemporary Orthodox understanding.

Comment: The Herman Wouk one looks great, and so does Horeb. Both in fact, seem quite promising! Thanks!

Comment: By the way, the first half of Horeb is available in English [online](http://www.stevens.edu/golem/llevine/rsrh/horebaphilosophy027897mbp.pdf) (apart from a few Hebrew volumes on HebrewBooks)

Comment: Second "This is My G-d"; it's fantastic. Also anything by Jonathan Sacks, including his talks

Answer (score 5):

Some book ideas (I'll add more if I think of them):

- I've never read it, but *[The Complete Idiot's Guide to Understanding Judaism](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/159257131X)* is supposed to be good, and the author, [Rabbi Benjamin Blech](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benjamin_Blech), is supposed to be a good guy (and Orthodox). This should serve as a useful survey.
- The novel *[With All My Heart, With All My Soul](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1880880016)* does a great job of portraying one subculture in American Orthodox Judaism from the inside, for outsiders. The pseudonymous author is apparently an Orthodox Rabbi.

Comment: Now you've inspired a new question.  Great novels featuring jewish observance and religious life.  I just love Chaim Potok's The Chosen, and My Name is Asher Lev, for example.

Comment: Rabbi Benjamin Blech is amazing.  He also writes for the Aish.com website.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another one.

[Nine Questions People Ask About Judaism](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671622617) [Paperback]
Dennis Prager

(The Intelligent Skeptic's Guide to Judaism)

Answer (score 4):

[Gateway to Judaism](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1422600300) by Rabbi Mordechai Becher

"Based on years of answering thousands of challenging inquiries, Becher's work blends elements of Jewish philosophy and law with an intensely practical explanation of how Jews actually live."

Answer (score 4):

I highly suggest you read [*The Non-Orthodox Jew's Guide to Orthodox Jews*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0615342736) by David Baum. It is exactly what it sounds like. You will understand a lot about traditional Judaism from this book.

Answer (score 3):

Here is yet another great book, [The Outsider's Guide to Orthodox Judaism](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0615211364) by Rabbi Arnie Singer.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya!

Comment: Thanks very much for bringing this suggestion. Could you please [edit] your post to include more information about why this resource would be particularly useful for the question at hand?

Answer (score 3):

A highly recommended book is "Masterplan" by [Rabbi Aryeh Carmell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryeh_Carmell).

Here's a [description](https://www.shopeichlers.com/products/masterplan/1963) of the book:

> Maybe you believe in God, but fail to see what this has to do with how
> one spends Friday night or which restaurant one eats in? Or maybe you
> think that the primary purpose of the mitzvot was to preserve Jewish
> identity—a function that has now been taken over by the State of
> Israel? Or perhaps you are Orthodox, but have no clear idea of the
> nature of the Torah’s overall aims or the structure of its value
> system? Masterplan shows that the mitzvot that have come down to us
> over the ages form a dynamic and comprehensive system designed to
> elevate human beings and establish a just and caring society that can
> serve as a model for all humanity to emulate. It was for this purpose
> that the Land of Israel was given by God to the Jewish people. We live
> in a tumultuous age when large sections of mankind are searching for
> guidance. Masterplan shows that Judaism’s program of mitzvot,
> encompassing all aspects of life—personal growth, interpersonal and
> family relationships, commerce, industry, government and
> environment—is eminently relevant to our contemporary concerns.

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I was asking about.

Answer (score 2):

Warren,

I enjoyed reading your question. I hope my answer is of some assistance.

The [Durants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Will_Durant) in their book the [Story of Civilization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Story_of_Civilization) write:

> As we have it, the Mishna (i.e., oral
>   teaching) is the result of much
>   editing  and interpolation since
>   Jehuda; even so it is a compact
>   summary, designed  for memorizing by
>   repetition, and therefore
>   tantalizingly terse and obscure  to
>   one who comes to it from any
>   background except that of Jewish life
>   and  history.

This is the case for practically all the literature put forth over the past two millennia since the Mishna by practicing orthodox Jews. That is, if your looking for the *real* stuff you may have some trouble "getting into it".

That said, you might try this introductory material on-line; 
[here](http://www.aish.com/jl/jnj/nj/80405497.html) and [here](http://www.shalom-center.org/english.htm).

Best to you,

David

Comment: I read that first link already before once.  Aish.com seems pretty great. I'm reading lots on the second one too.  I am, I must confess, addicted to reading those offline objects composed of paper, so I hope someone comes along with a book idea, too.

Comment: Check the "Books" link at the Shalom Center http://www.shalom-center.org/lectuur.htm