# Status of Catholic saints in Judaism

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, christianity

Roman Catholics and other branches of Christianity have a concept of sainthood, where they bestow a status to someone based on posthumous miracles attributed to them. They also [pray to them](http://www.catholic.com/tracts/praying-to-the-saints).

Generally in discussing Avodah Zarah or Shittuf issues with Christianity, the focus tends to be on their founding figure. But what is the status of things attributed to "saints," most specifically images or symbols of them?

Is this also regarded as an Avodah Zarah on equal status with, for example, a cross, or does it have some lesser status?

Comment: Baruch shekivanti. About a month back I was going to ask this very question.however in researching this I came to the conclusion that catholics in fact do not pray to saints, they do not consider them to be part of the Godhead, rather they view them as conduits to their deity lehavdil but similar to tzaddikim being meilitz yosher for us. Right now I don't have the sources which support that but hopefully later I will.

Comment: @Mefaresh speaking as a Catholic (if that is appropriate) you are correct; we do not believe that saints are in any sense equal to or part of the Deity. Rather, they are treated as trusted friends whom we can approach to request their prayers for us. Has Judaism such a concept?

Comment: @MattGutting Judaism has a slightly similar concept in that we believe that the righteous who have passed can due to their merits serve as representative for us to plead our case and for our favor. But in no way shape or form do we ever pray to them.

Comment: @MattGutting, yes it does. There are also opponents within Judaism to doing that. However, one distinction I see is that the Catholic saint is granted some sort of official status, and I get the impression (although I don't know) the prayer is more "praying" for intercession rather than a simple request.

Comment: @Mefaresh, I think it is an exaggeration to say "in no way shape or form do we pray to them". Although it isn't prayer, going to Kivrei Avos, etc. and actually asking that they should pray for us, is part of Judaism, and there are official texts about it as well.

Comment: @Yishai I needever heard of praying to the mes. If so I have no idea on what basis it is allowed.

Comment: Thanks @Yishai. We do make simple "requests" too - especially from "patron saints" - e.g. I might ask Saint Dymphna, patron saint of people with epilepsy, to ask for the favor of not having a seizure today.

Comment: @MattGutting why is it permitted according to catholicism to beseech the Saint to not have a seizure. Does that not assume that they have divine powers which allows them to stop it or decree it?

Comment: @Mefaresh No, we ask the saint to ask God not to let us have a seizure; God grants the favor. Could we go up a level and ask God directly? Absolutely. But sometimes people feel more comfortable talking to someone who's been in our position.

Comment: @MattGutting, see, that would go to far in Judaism. At most you would ask that they ask G-d for some good outcome.

Comment: @Mefaresh, see [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44719/do-jews-pray-to-deceased-forefathers)

Comment: @Yishai thanks! Does Mi Yodeya have any reference to a standard set of resources that can be used to learn "the basics" about Judaism?

Comment: @MattGutting, Well, it has a [question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10739/resources-for-learning-about-the-foundations-of-judaism) about that, and some solid answers to the question.

Answer (score 1):

According to Catholic Doctrine Catholics do not pray to Saints as a deity-thus it would not be considered "shittuf" as they are not joining or raising Saints to the level of the Divine. Rather, [according to this site](http://www.catholic.com/tracts/praying-to-the-saints) Catholics use them as emmisaries and intermediaries  in their requests, and that the saint will argue for you to their deity.

[According to this site the difference lies between prayer and worship](http://catholicism.about.com/od/thesaints/f/Pray_to_Saints.htm):

> The Difference Between Prayer and Worship
>
> Many non-Catholic Christians believe that it is wrong to pray to the
>   saints, claiming that our prayers should be directed to God alone.
>   Some Catholics, responding to this criticism, have argued that we do
>   not pray to the saints but with them.Both groups, however, are
>   confusing prayer with worship. True worship (as opposed to veneration
>   or honor) does indeed belong to God alone, and we should never worship
>   man or any other creature as we worship God. But while worship may
>   take the form of prayer, as in the Mass and other liturgies of the
>   Church, not all prayer is worship. When we pray to the saints, we’re
>   simply asking them to help us, by praying to God on our behalf, or
>   thanking them for having already done so.

Seemingly, there is precedence in Judaism for such a concept- albeit radically different than the Christian concept (they are not considered close "friends" and there are no tzaddikim set aside as "charms" for specific needs or requests) this mirrors the practice of asking Tzaddikim to be a "meilitz yosher" or an advocate in heaven.

This idea is mentioned in [Gesher HaChaim Volume 2 25:9](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31172&st=&pgnum=201&hilite=) in the name of the [Zohar Parshas Acharei Mos](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14354&st=&pgnum=139)

Comment: "albeit radically different" How is it radically different?

Comment: We don't thank tzaddikim. Hodaah belongs to Hashem alone

Comment: ??? You can't thank a Tzaddik for interceding on your behalf? What happened to Hakarat HaTov?

Comment: Hodaah is G-d's alone. And after the fact how can you know that this deceased tzaddik was the reason?

Comment: Thank him for trying? Seems like the polite thing to do.

Comment: I don't even know what that means

Comment: Go to his grave and say "Hi Mr. Tzaddik. Good to be back. Your tombstone is looking mighty clean today. I got what I wanted in the end from God. It's really nice. I don't know exactly what you did up there but I really appreciate whatever it was. Thanks for your help. See you later!" I really have no idea why you claim "Hodaah is G-d's alone" when I thank living humans all the time for things.

Comment: You thank living humans for interceding for your to G-d all the time? Who are these great tzaddikim that have such power

Comment: The mainstream Torah scholars who addressed this issue (e.g. the Rambam, Ramban, Vlina Gaon, and Maharal MiPrague all considered praying to intermediaries to be idolatry.

Comment: @Mefaresh I thank living people for doing normal things. I give them Hodaah. What does it matter what I'm thanking them for? Re your second question: I have no idea but a lot of Jews apparently seem to think they know the right people.

Comment: @loewian: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44719/do-jews-pray-to-deceased-forefathers

Comment: http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/562222/jewish/Is-it-okay-to-ask-a-deceased-tzaddik-to-pray-on-my-behalf.htm

Comment: `Catholics use them as emmisaries and intermediaries in their requests, and that the saint will argue for you to their deity.` Serving God through an intermediary is totally forbidden according to Rambam. He implies that it is Avodah Zara.