# Interest in Judaism, but no experience with it

Tags: jewish-books, books-generally

Where is a good place for someone to start out who is interested in Judaism but has no prior experience with it?

Comment: http://www.jewfaq.org/

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10739/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6988/759

Comment: @msh210 why do you assume he is asking for a book

Comment: @m.r. because of the OP's tagging.

Comment: I just used those tags because I was not sure of what tag to use for this particular question.

Comment: But are you, in fact, looking for books? Then you're in luck -- that older question provides a list. (And if you want to be sure that other users will see your comments here, then see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting ).