# Recommendation of Books

Tags: jewish-books, conversion-to-judaism

What books a person pursuing a orthodox conversion normally must read during the entire process. I want to convert in bnei brak

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Fernanda. Based on your question, I will assume you are already in Bnei Brak in touch with a Beit Din for conversion there. The best thing for you to do is ask them for instruction in this area. They will likely put you in touch with an individual for specific counseling. With wishes for blessings of revealed good in your pursuits.

Comment: You should ask the rav assigned by the beis din in Bnai Brak to teach you.

Comment: i didn't explain it right. i'm in Brazil pursuing a conversion in Bnei Brak. i haven't started my conversion yet.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12648/170

Comment: You might also find this useful: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/95567/11501