# Good, recent textbook that faithfully describe Orthodox and/or Conservative Judaism

Tags: jewish-books

Does Dan Cohn-Sherbok's 2017 textbook  [Judaism: History, Belief and Practice, 2nd Ed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XWDY8S3) situate and represent fairly Orthodox Judaism and Conservative Judaism within the full spectrum of Judaism?  (I'm using the labels as introduced [here](https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/the-jewish-denominations/)).

I welcome suggestions for other textbooks that focus on Orthodox or Conservative denominations.

Comment: Given that the author is Reform, I would expect his work to reflect that orientation. If you are looking for a broad sketch of Jewish history, reflective of Orthodox sentiments you might enjoy "Sand and Stars" (2 volumes) by Yaffa Ganz and Rabbi Berel Wein.

Comment: Rabbi Berel Wein also wrote other textbooks that my Orthodox high school used for history class.

Comment: Benjamin Blech's "Idiot's Guide to Judaism" is often recommended, from an Orthodox perspective. (Not "Judaism for Dummies.")

Comment: @Shalom Thank you everyone. Author's affiliation definitely needs to be considered, something I need help with from this site.

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/95567/11501) helpful - if you are looking for more specific books, please be more specific in your question and we'll try and help