# What is a lost Jew to do?

Tags: tzibur-community, judaism

I am a Jew because my parents are Jews and their parents are too. I have recently come to believe in G-d through G-d but I have no communication with my Jewish people.

Do the sources require that everyone finds their place in the Jewish community to fulfil their Jewishness and if so how is it done?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! I wish you much success on your journey to reclaim your heritage. We can't offer personal counseling, so I would strongly recommend that you find a local rabbi to talk to, to point you in a productive educational and communal direction

Comment: I have edited your question to narrow it down and to stop it being a personal enquiry. If you don't approve, you can return to the original question.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! There are many organizations that work to help people in your position reconnect to their heritage. Here's a list of some of the most well-known organizations: https://jewish-links.yolasite.com/kiruv.php. Judaism is extremely community focused, so while one could technically be Jewish  on an island, they would miss out on some of the most enriching and fulfilling parts.

Comment: You need to connect with other Jews in person, it would be easier to provide guidance if we knew in what country/city you live

Comment: It would be in a Jewish community is well. Welcome.

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2944949/jewish/I-Just-Discovered-Im-Jewish.htm

Answer (score 6):

Welcome back.

Fulfilling your Jewishness means learning about your obligations as a Jew, called *mitzvot*, commandments, so you can fulfill them. Which means you need to learn Torah. I collected [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/95567/11501) resources for a beginner wanting to do so. There are plenty of online resources as well (start [here at chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/109866/jewish/Essentials.htm) for instance).

Most important is to find a guide in learning to live as a Jew, ideally a trained rabbi who has helped others in your circumstances. For this you should turn to one of your local Orthodox Jewish communities, hoping there are one or more where you live. That rabbi can help design the right growth plan for you, which will likely include participating in community events, Shabbatot, holidays, etc.

Feel free to ask more questions here if we can be of help.

Answer (score 0):

[The  Gemoro Sanhedrin 17b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.17b.10?lang=bi) says that a talmid haham (scholar) is not allowed to live in a city that does not have these 10 things: a beit din (law court) that metes out punishments; a fund that is collected by two people and distributed by three; a synagogue; a bath house; a bathroom; a doctor; a craftsperson; a blood-letter; (some versions add: a butcher); and a teacher of children.” If you are not a scholar, maybe this does not apply. But another fundamental part of  Judaism is learning Torah and so we should all be scholars.

[My Jewish Learning](https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/community-focused/) has an article explaining the importance of the community in Judaism.

I cannot prove that community is essential, but it surely is advisable. I suggest you research Jewish life near where you live (Google “jewish life "my location"") and try https://www.chabad.org/jewish-centers/

Comment: I am a Kohanim, a servant of the Holy Spirit.  My question was edited, but it was G-d  who spoke to me and instructed me to read Pslam 23 and I came to a new understanding instantly. G-d changed my heart from dead to living.  

Community is not essential for these things as you can see; I am a lost Jew, but not lost from G-d; He is with me and I with Him. He has not abandoned me, even in my confusion with what a Jew is exactly.  

I know for certain, it is the Jew in me that is the reason for these things. I cannot be a true Christian, because I am what I am and I seek for wise counsel.

Comment: You might like to read [this article](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/762109/jewish/Raise-Your-Hand-If-Youre-A-Kohen.htm) especially the section headed "What does it mean to be a kohen?".

Comment: Thank you, I understand. What good is a kohen who is lost from his tribe? This has answered my question. I am no good to the Jew if I am far from understanding what it is we are. I will be seen as a familiar stranger to my kind. Like a duck that learned to bark like a dog, but has not learned  how to quack like the flock. 

 It is G-d that commands us to come to understand community and fellowship, to be in unity for our Lord’s glory. 

I cannot be a kohen by understanding alone, it must be shared,  we cannot share with the unfamiliar, we must also know the ways of our people to be one.