# How to introduce oneself to Judaism as an adult?

Tags: jewish-books, adult-learning

I wasn't brought up in the Hebrew tradition (I was brought up as a catholic) but I have become interested about Judaism as an adult.

I don't have almost any knowledge about Judaism, I have read the catholic Bible and all my knowledge about Judaism came from there.

I would like to read more about it because I believe that there are a lot of topics of Hebrew life that are not explained very deeply in what I've read so far.

What lectures would you recommend to an adult with little previous knowledge of Judaism to gain some insight and understand Hebrew traditions?

I know that there are a lot of different groups which may differ in some aspects but, as I have no previous knowledge, I would like to read something as general as possible.

Comment: This looks pretty good https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judaism#  ,

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6988

Comment: This website is well paced, and clearly written: http://www.jewfaq.org/toc.htm