# Audio shiurim/podcasts for beginners or geirim?

Tags: product-recommendation, conversion-to-judaism, adult-learning

I'm wondering if anyone can recommend a podcast (or shiurim by a particular speaker) that would be relatively easily available (i.e. on iTunes, YUTorah or something similar) that would be helpful for laying out various aspects of Judaism but in a way that would be accessible to someone who is involved in the geirus process and/or for someone who grew up Jewish but not observant. Basically looking for introductions to basic ideas (both halacha and 'philosophy') that don't require too much background knowledge or too much knowledge of Hebrew/Yeshivish terms. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Somewhat related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6988

Answer (score 4):

Here are some sites with audio content which I have used at different points in time with a focus on beginners

- [Aish](https://aishaudio.com/)
- [Ohr Somayach](https://audio.ohr.edu/)
- [Chabad](http://www.chabad.org/multimedia/default_cdo/aid/6230/jewish/Audio-Classes.htm)
- [torah.org](https://torah.org/) - split by shiurim by "complexity level"
- [simpletoremember](https://www.simpletoremember.com/media/)

Re podcasts, there is a large list [here](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/genre/podcasts-judaism/id1441?mt=2) - specific content focused on beginners include [R Jonathan Sacks](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/podcast/office-of-rabbi-sacks/id796183168?mt=2)