# Learning Torah in places with no Yeshivot

Tags: product-recommendation, torah-study

There are still many people in this world who want to learn Torah but do not have a chance yet due to the fact that there are no yeshivot around etc.

What would be the best and easiest way for studying **Torah** privately and formally (he may have some Rabbis in contact)?

Comment: Purely Avot teaches us: "הוי  גולה למקום תורה" you should leave your place and go to the place where the Torah is learned.

Comment: Not every one can do that.

Comment: Such a person could contact Aish Hatorah, online or by phone. Alternatively, he could contact Chabad, if he is so inclined. Both of them will do their best to find him a suitable study framework.

Comment: After he practices Judaism why should he do Teshuva? And how Teshuva is related to Torah study?

Answer (score 5):

1. Torah study was never limited to Yeshivos, one can learn Torah at home, at Shul, practically anywhere.
2. Learning Torah in Yeshivos is only formal for kids not for adults, similarly to regular schools.
3. Learning Torah is not limited to books either, one can listen to lectures or live Rabbis. One can also learn with a Chevruta over the phone.
4. Learning Torah has no fixed curriculum, one can learn whatever he pleases - Chumash, Gemmarah, Halachah, Midrashim, philosophy etc. One can start at any place, any Parasha, any Masechet, any chapter. THere's no fixed amount of information one has to cover.
5. There's no fixed pace either. Some like to follow Daily portions (such as חוק לישראל or Daily Daf of Gemmorah or Daily Rambam etc).
6. There's no minimum time requirement. One who learns once a week or an hour per day or 8 hours a day, is considered a Torah learner if he put it in his best effort and priority.

Comment: I would only add to this excellent answer that a Jew should try his best to incorporate certain basic subjects into his Torah study. This includes Chumash, Halachos, and Gemara if he is capable of it, as detailed in Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah Hilchos Talmud Torah.

Comment: Can you please post that S"A

Comment: Yoreh Deah 246:4 חַיָּב אָדָם לְשַׁלֵּשׁ לִמּוּדוֹ, שְׁלִישׁ בַּתּוֹרָה שֶׁבִּכְתָב, דְּהַיְנוּ הָאַרְבָּעָה וְעֶשְׂרִים; שְׁלִישׁ בְּמִשְׁנָה, דְּהַיְנוּ תּוֹרָה שֶׁבְּעַל פֶּה, וּפֵרוּשׁ תּוֹרָה שֶׁבִּכְתָב בִּכְלַל זֶה; שְׁלִישׁ בְּתַלְמוּד, דְּהַיְנוּ שֶׁיָּבִין וְיַשְׂכִּיל אַחֲרִית דָּבָר מֵרֵאשִׁיתוֹ,

Comment: Translation: One is obligated to divide his learning schedule into thirds: one third in Written Torah; that is, the twenty-four [books of the Tanach]; one third in Mishna, that is, the Torah She'b'al Peh, and the explanations of the Written Torah are included herein; [and] one third to Talmud, that is understanding and conceptualizing the end of a matter from its beginnings..

Comment: See Commentators there, who explain that since we do not learn Halachah straight from the Gemara anymore, we must study Halachah separately. This is also explained in the introduction of the Mishnah Berurah.

Comment: @shmu It's a completely different question. The beginners are free to choose whatever they feel interesting and entertaining.

Comment: Since the OP is seeking the best way to learn Torah, I think it is appropriate to mention what the Torah itself has to say about that.

Comment: I think that the approach of @Al Berko is the best, that a beginner should learn what he likes. Nevertheless, just for the record, I wanted to mention that regular study of Mussar is an obligation according to the Chafetz Chaim and many others. Especially if you like Mussar and find it interesting, it's a recommended subject.

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of resources on the Internet to learn Torah (and I listed many [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/92616/11501) and [there](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/86926/11501)), however you are correct that one needs a teacher to define a formal learning program, make sure content is understood and answer questions.

Two organizations that can help arrange for such teachers and one-on-one learning are

- [Partners in Torah](https://www.partnersintorah.org/) (see [here](https://www.ou.org/partners/) for different "entry doors")
- [JInspire](http://www.jinspire.org/one-on-one)